# copy the variable by changing some of its node value using template in XSLT

Tags: xslt

```
<transaction>
    <itemConfirmation>
       <catalogueItemConfirmationState>
 <catalogueItemConfirmationStateCode>REVIEW</catalogueItemConfirmationStateCode>
       </catalogueItemConfirmationState>
       <catalogueItemReference>
          //some data           
        </catalogueItemReference>
   </itemConfirmation>
</transaction>
```

> The **transaction** node i am passing to removeEmptyTransaction template 
>   I want to change value of **catalogueItemConfirmationStateCode** only if the transaction contains **catalogueItemReference** and then copy entire transaction node in output .Their are multiple transaction node and the catalogueItemReference optional.

```
<xsl:template name="removeEmptyTransaction">
   <xsl:param name="eachTransactionElement"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$eachTransactionElement"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Please suggest..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, write a template with e.g. `match="transaction[.//catalogueItemReference]//catalogueItemConfirmationStateCode"` that implements the change you need (you haven't explained which one you want) and then push your variable through that transformation with `<xsl:apply-templates select="$eachTransactionElement"/>`. Of course that approach also needs the identity transformation template in place to make sure the rest is copied unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for your response..The issue is i am calling removeEmptyTransaction from multiple places. `eachTransactionElement` is a variable containing entire transaction  and i want to copy that in output at the end after manipulation.Can you please suggest where should i write that template..

Comment: I don't see why you need to use a named template at all. If you simply want that template to transform the `transaction` element(s) then use the suggested approach and instead of calling the named template with a parameter all you need is use e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="transaction"/>`.

Comment: Thank for the answer.but the transaction element is not from source XML it is generated in XSLT.So how to add match condition.I really appreciate your help

Comment: With XSLT 2 and later it does not matter whether it is a source document or some temporary tree. With XSLT 1 you need `exsl:node-set` on your variable.